# Chromium doesnt recognise daylight saving time

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, chromium, dst

Im running Chromium 56 on a Raspberry Pi. When I request the time, via javaScript, Chromium is behaving as if there is no DayLight Saving Time (DST) in operation. That is to say, .toString(), .toLocaleString() and .toUTCString() all return the same time. Also, .getTimezoneOffset() returns zero. (It should be +0100 here in the UK). Is this a bug, or is there a setting somewhere in Chromium that has not been made?  (Just to confirm, the computer itself does know the correct time). I cannot think of any workaround other than to fetch the timezone offset from the web server by various means (e.g. via Ajax or getting PHP to echo a javaScript script in the HTML page being parsed).

Comment: What timezone is the RPi using?

Comment: I was _about_ to say Europe/London and that it was _Chromium_ that was in error, but ... I thought I should check, and the timezone was _not set_. Setting it has cured my problem. **Apologies for wasting everyone's time!**  Im running a web server on the RPi, and PHP was reporting the correct time, but JavaScript was not recognising DST. But... I had configured PHP for Europe/London, and didnt realise that the timezone was unset in the RPi.